# Give a user access to extended_properties by not to VIEW DEFINITION

Tags: sql-server

After noting that nobody seemed to have answer for this, I came up with a solution that works for me. So this is an answer, rather than a question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to give a user access to extended properties, you have to do this:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::XDB TO AUSER
GRANT SELECT on sys.extended_properties to AUSER
```

But that means the user can ALSO SEE all the source code SP's functions etc.. We don't want that! Now, other issues aside, what I want to do is allow a user (AUSER) to see some extended properties, but WITHOUT giving them the ability to view the source code.

Create a non-login user who can do that:

```
CREATE USER EXTPROP WITHOUT LOGIN
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON DATABASE::XDB TO EXTPROP;
GRANT SELECT on sys.extended_properties to EXTPROP
-- use master
-- go
-- GRANT IMPERSONATE on LOGIN::EXTPROP TO AUSER
```

Now create a function that AUSER can execute.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ShowVersion
WITH EXECUTE AS 'EXTPROP'
AS
select * from sys.extended_properties
where class_desc = 'DATABASE' and name = 'version'

GRANT EXECUTE ON ShowVersion to AUSER
```

To test, login to SSMS as AUSER and execute these:

```
exec showversion -- returns result
select suser_sname() -- returns AUSER (no need to REVERT)
select * from sys.extended_properties  
where class_desc = 'DATABASE' and name = 'version' -- returns no rows
```

Comment: Nice. Two comments: I don't think the ability to impersonate the login is strictly necessary, just execute permission on the stored procedure. I don't have a test environment handy, but try to revoke the impersonate permission and see if your solution still works. Also, I don't really care about this sort of thing, but this site doesn't really seem geared for posting your own question merely for the sake of answering it. That's what blogs are for.

Comment: 1. asking a question that no-one has an answer for, means the next person who searches this site for this solution, finds one here - and I do think this is the purpose of stack-overflow. 2. I agree that I don't need to do login impersonation to achieve this.

Comment: All I'm saying is that it could be viewed as pandering for rep. Like I said... I don't really care about that because it's just a number in a database somewhere.